# How to find the difference between two time in ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
time_difference_in_sec = (DateTime.now - @given_time).to_i.abs

where DateTime.now : #<DateTime: 2015-09-28T19:30:35+05:30 ((2457294j,50435s,957360402n),+19800s,2299161j)>
@given_time : #<DateTime: 2015-09-28T11:30:09+00:00 ((2457294j,41409s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

time_difference_in_sec : 0
```

I searched a lot but didn't get the proper answer.

Comment: There is million versions of this question already, but anyway... There is methods in Ruby’s Date, like [`<<`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-3C-3C), which provides operations of substraction and addition of days, months and other units you may want to add or substract.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want it in seconds, you can just convert both to time stamps, and then subtract

```
time_difference_in_sec = (DateTime.now.to_time.to_i - @given_time.to_time.to_i).abs
```

Else you wind up dealing with rational numbers, and the like as seen in the other answers..

Answer (score 3):

`-` operator returns difference in seconds:

```
2.2.1 :002 > 1.day.ago - 2.days.ago
 => 86399.999778025 
2.2.1 :005 > (1.day.ago - 2.days.ago)/1.day
 => 0.9999999986567014
```

Comment: Note that the `days` methods are provided by ActiveSupport, not by Ruby.

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime.now - @given_time   # get the number of days
((DateTime.now - @given_time) * 24 * 3600).to_i # get seconds

(DateTime.now - @given_time).class
=> Rational
```

> Rational: A rational number can be represented as a paired integer number; a/b (b>0). Where a is numerator and b is denominator. Integer a equals rational a/1 mathematically.